# Opening Movieclip AS3 short cut

Tags: actionscript-3, shortcut

Is there a way, other than double clicking, to open a selected movie clip/button/group in flash?

Best 
Luben

Comment: What do you mean? Is this is a programming question, of course, yes! If this is a user interface question, you're in the wrong place

Comment: I just click ask question and I ask! but sorry next time I'll be more careful and pay attention where I ask questions..

Comment: No apologies necessary :) This site is about programming related questions. People should be able to come here in a few years and easily find answers to their questions, this is why the content needs to remain focused.

Comment: You're right. This site is the best and I love the people who make it possible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try Right Click > Edit in Place